# Node JS - AWS Lambda Asynchronous response with RDS Database Connectivity

Tags: node.js, lambda

I am trying to connect to DB and log the response, but the code is throwing ask timed out after x.00 seconds.

This code is running in AWS Lambda function. i am using node js.
Require help in understanding where i am going wrong.

```
'use strict';
 const {Client} = require('pg');
 var clientHandler;
 let response;
 var sqlString = "select * from fleet.instance_aio";
 exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
   await connectToDb();
   await queryDB();
   return response;
   };

async function connectToDb() {
try {
    clientHandler = new Client({
        user: process.env.USER,
        host: process.env.HOST,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.PORT
    });
    clientHandler.connect();
    console.log(`DB Connection SuccessFull.`);
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(`DB Connection Failed. Error Details is ${error}`);
    throw new Error("DBConnectionFailed");
   }
   }

async function queryDB() {
   let dbResponse = await clientHandler.query(sqlString);
    console.log("Query executed");
    console.log('The solution is: ', JSON.stringify(dbResponse));
    clientHandler.end();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened because the action inside lambda takes more than 3 seconds.

The default timeout is 3 seconds so it is needed to change the default timeout of that lambda function.

Comment: I increased it to 10 minutes, but it looks like code is not getting completed. Ite being running forever.

Comment: Yes, i get DB Connection SuccessFull logged in console.

Comment: How have you called that lambda? Tried on aws console?

Comment: It gets timeout in the line 

let dbResponse = await clientHandler.query(sqlString);

Comment: What is `fleet.instance_aio`?

Comment: its tablename. i am able to run that query when i run in non async mode.

Comment: This will help. https://node-postgres.com/features/queries